# How to wrap golang test functions

Tags: go

I'd like to wrap standard golang test functions, such as `t.Errorf` from the testing package.

I tried this:

```
// AssertEqual tests that the expected and actual values match
func AssertEqual(t *testing.T, expected interface{}, actual interface{}) {
    switch expected.(type) {
    case string:
        if expected != actual {
            t.Errorf("Error:\nexpected: %s\nactual: %s", expected, actual)
        }
    default:
        t.Errorf("Unsupported type")
    }
}
```

However, when a test fails, I get the function and line number of my helper function:

```
test_asserts.go:12: Error:
    expected: 
    actual: TestValue
```

**Is there a way to error at the line number of the caller?**

Comment: One year later, with Go 1.9, adding `t.Helper()` will make the line number to be the correct one. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45897453/6309)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the testing library does it:
https://golang.org/src/testing/testing.go?h=Errorf#L285

By using `runtime.Caller`.

You can borrow this code for your own error function that would look one deeper into the stack.  You can replace the entirety of `Errorf` (which is `log` + `fail`) or a bit less pretty but less code would be to just print the entire stack using something like `debug.PrintStack()` before calling `Errorf`.

Answer (score 13):

With the recent Go 1.9 (August 2017), all you need to do is adding one line to your function:

```
t.Helper()
```

That will silence this function in error report, and your actual error line will be the one you expect (ie the one calling this function)

See [`pkg/testing/#T.Helper`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.Helper) (also available for [Benchmark test](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#B.Helper), but... not for the [`TB` interface](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#TB), where [it was forgotten](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/Atgo-EG1uN0)! Feb. 2021: this is available, see below)

```
// AssertEqual tests that the expected and actual values match
func AssertEqual(t *testing.T, expected interface{}, actual interface{}) {
    t.Helper()
    switch expected.(type) {
    case string:
        if expected != actual {
            t.Errorf("Error:\nexpected: %s\nactual: %s", expected, actual)
        }
    default:
        t.Errorf("Unsupported type")
    }
}
```

[xuiqzy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4288004/xuiqzy) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194816/how-to-wrap-golang-test-functions/45897453#comment116891322_45897453) in Feb. 2021 the interface [`testing.TB`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#TB) which now has `Helper()`.
See [commit bc29313, Apr. 2017, go1.9beta1](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/bc2931372243043842161c0a60bd2f86ef9696ee), [CL 38796](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/38796/) for implementing [proposal 4899](https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/master/design/4899-testing-helper.md).

> We propose to add a new `testing.TB` method, `Helper`, which marks the calling function as a test helper.
>
> When logging test messages, package testing ignores frames that are inside marked helper functions.
> It prints the first stack position inside a non-helper function.

Comment: Now also available in `TB` interface: https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#TB

Comment: @xuiqzy Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can see `Fail` function in `assert` package: https://github.com/stretchr/testify/blob/master/assert/assertions.go#L207

Example:

```
package main_test

import (
        "fmt"
        "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
        "strings"
        "testing"
)

// AssertEqual tests that the expected and actual values match
func AssertEqual(t *testing.T, expected interface{}, actual interface{}) {
        switch expected.(type) {
        case string:
                if expected != actual {
                        callInfo := assert.CallerInfo()
                        errorTrace := strings.Join(callInfo, "\n\r\t\t\t")
                        t.Errorf("\r%s\r\tError Trace:\t%s\n"+
                                "\r\tError:%s\n\r",
                                "",
                                errorTrace,
                                fmt.Sprintf("Error:\nexpected: %s\nactual: %s", expected, actual),
                        )
                }
        default:
                t.Errorf("Unsupported type")
        }
}                                                                                                                                                                                            

func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {                                                                                                                                                                 
        AssertEqual(t, "hello", 21)                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

Result:

```
$ go test main_test.go 
--- FAIL: TestFoo (0.00s)
        Error Trace::22:main_test.go:15
                        main_test.go:30
        Error:Error:
                expected: hello
                actual: %!s(int=21)

FAIL
FAIL    command-line-arguments  0.002s
```